# Get a row from Excel with different criterias with one method

Tags: java, excel

Using Apache POI, I want to retrieve a `Person` from my Excel file by `id` or by `name`. To keep the example simple, the `Person` class is only an `int id` a `String name` and in the Excel file, the `id` starts at A2 (A1 is the header) and the `name` at B2 (B1 is the header).

I came up with this code:

ExcelDB class:

```
package datasource;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import model.Person;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;

public class ExcelDB implements Repository {
    private static XSSFRow row;
    private static final String datasource = "src/doc/Classeur1.xlsx";

    public ExcelDB(){
    }

    @Override
    public Person getPersonById(int id) {
        return queryExcel(id);
    }

    @Override
    public Person getPersonByName(String name) {
        return queryExcel(name);
    }

    private Person queryExcel(Object arg){
        File file = new File(datasource);
        FileInputStream fis;
        Boolean find;
        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream(file);

            XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
            XSSFSheet spreadsheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
            Iterator<Row> rowIterator = spreadsheet.iterator();

            //Skip header
            rowIterator.next();
            while (rowIterator.hasNext())
            {
                row = (XSSFRow) rowIterator.next();
                if (arg instanceof String) //When it's a name
                    find = ((String)arg).equals(row.getCell(1).getStringCellValue());
                else if (arg instanceof Integer) //When it's an ID
                    find = ((int)arg) == (int)row.getCell(0).getNumericCellValue();
                else
                    find = false;
                if (find)
                    return new Person((int)row.getCell(0).getNumericCellValue(), row.getCell(1).getStringCellValue());
            }
            fis.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ExcelDB.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Datasource class:

```
package datasource;

import model.Person;

public class Datasource implements Repository {
    private final ExcelDB datasource;

    private Datasource(){
        datasource = new ExcelDB();
    }

    public static Datasource instance = null;
    public static Datasource getInstance(){
        if (instance == null)
            instance = new Datasource();
        return instance;
    }

    @Override
    public Person getPersonById(int id) {
        return datasource.getPersonById(id);
    }

    @Override
    public Person getPersonByName(String name) {
        return datasource.getPersonByName(name);
    }
}
```

Repository interface:

```
package datasource;

import model.Person;

public interface Repository {
    public Person getPersonById(int id);
    public Person getPersonByName(String name);
}
```

Person class:

```
package model;

public class Person {
    private int id;
    private String name;

    public Person(int id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Person{" + "id=" + id + ", name=" + name + '}';
    }
}
```

And my testing main class:

```
package test;

import datasource.Datasource;
import model.Person;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Datasource datasource = Datasource.getInstance();

        Person person = datasource.getPersonById(5);
        System.out.println(person.toString());

        person = datasource.getPersonByName("Alec");
        System.out.println(person.toString());
    }
}
```

Excel file:

```
ID  NAME
1   Alec
2   Bob
3   Charlie
4   Derp
5   Émilie
6   Félix
7   Gage
```

I wanted the code to be simple and non-repetitive, but I don't know if using `instanceof` like I did is a good idea (as I may want to use other attributes to retrieve a `Person`). Also, everytime I use one of my public methods, the file has to be opened and closed, so I wonder if there is another way to do it.

Answer (score 3):

#### `ExcelDB`

I'm focusing on this class since it's what you originally posted for review <sup><sup><sup>and I really don't wanna spend hours reviewing every class</sup></sup></sup>

The biggest is that you're taking an `Object` so you can pass in either a `String` or an `int` (which gets [autoboxed/unboxed](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/autoboxing.html) to `Integer`, incidentally). You can fix this by making an overloaded method, but that has a ton of repeated code, unless you do what I mention in the next paragraph.

The `queryExcel` method is big. It does a lot of things -- opens the file, reads it as a bunch of sheets, searches, etc. That should probably be split into a bunch of methods, which has the side bonus of lowering code duplication if you choose to go with overloaded methods instead of taking an `Object`.

You open and close the file every single time which, since it never changes, makes no sense. I'd recommend making that a persistent variable, if it weren't for the fact that that makes it incredibly hard to reliably close when done.

However, there is something you can do to eliminate a bit of worry about leaving it unclosed if any of the operations between opening and closing throw an error: Use the try-with-resources statement:

```
try (FileInputStream fis = /* ... */) {
    // Same code in here
    // No fis.close() at the end!
} catch (/* Whatever exceptions opening might cause */) {
    //...
}
```

Related to your `try`, it's generally a bad idea to catch `Exception`. Here, it doesn't matter so much, since the action taken is always the same, but it'd be preferable to catch, say, `IOException` instead, so if you get an unexpected error type, it gets thrown and crashes your program, which in turn lets you find the bug without waiting for it to crop up later and tracing it all the way back to an exception that you only logged.

I like how you comment the first `rowIterator.next()` to explain why -- that's a fantastic habit to get into.

The standard spacing I see for casting is `(NewT) oldVariable` -- note the space between. It doesn't actually matter, but I find it more readable, personally.

Java has `boolean`. Don't use `Boolean` in its place. Sure, they look almost the same, but one is a primitive type and the other is an object type.

Why is `find` declared so far up? It's never used except in the `try`, and even then only in one small area. Why not define it there?

I don't know anything about the API you're using, so I can't say if you're using it badly. A few glances at the official docs and examples make it look like you're doing fine, though.

One thing that I see people mentioning and I almost missed: Try to avoid skipping braces. Sure, it's *possible* if you only have one line, but it can lead to bugs, and it's safer just to have brackets.

---

What's the purpose of `Datasource`? It seems like you're trying to get the strategy pattern, but at compile-time; that could be done just by using `ExcelDB` directly though. As far as I can tell, it's just a meaningless wrapper, and should be removed.

Along those lines, you never use `Repository`, at least in the code provided. If it's used elsewhere, it should (obviously) be kept, but as-is, it serves no purpose.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. The purpose of `Datasource` is that the Excel file might not be the only source of my data (will probably add CSV, JSON and some kind of actual database). That way I'll just add the `csvDB`, `jsonDB` and `w/eDB` class implementing the `Repository` interface and change the `datasource` in the `Datasource` class. Although it may be pointless to do so. I've also modified my code to only open once the Excel file, but I never close it. It works just fine, but might it cause problems?

Comment: @Artyom2033 ...`Datasource` is still useless. Just change it in your code, so that if you want to check which one you're reading from, you don't have to go to another class -- you can see it right where you declare your variable. And yes, opening without closing can cause problems, though I doubt it will in this specific case since it's such a small program. It's a leak nonetheless, and not a good habit to make.

Answer (score 2):

### General

All of your classes should be final, as none of them are designed to be extended.

In java, `static final` member variables are named in uppercase. For instance, `ExcelDB.datasource` should be `DATASOURCE`.

### Datasource

Don't use single-check locking in `Datasource`. You probably don't need lazy-load - just do `private static final Datasource INSTANCE = new Datasource()`. The only possible difference is if somebody statically references your class and doesn't call `getInstance()`, which is not currently possible. If you really need lazy load, use the [holder idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21604243/correct-implementation-of-initialization-on-demand-holder-idiom).

`Datasource` is questionable. If you're trying to hide the selected implementation of `Repository` from the client, use a `Factory` class which returns a `Repository`, and have `ExcelDB`, etc implement `Repository`.

`Datasource` should not expose `instance` as a `public` variable.

### Person

`Person` has an identity crisis. Either it should be immutable, in which case there should be no setters and the member variables should be final, or it should be a bean, in which case there should be a no-arg constructor. Prefer the former when possible.

`Person#toString()` would be cleaner using `String#format()`, such as `return String.format("Person{id=%d, name=%s}", this.id, this.name);`

### ExcelDB

`ExcelDB` should not be public, since the idea is to hide it behind the `Repository` interface. If it's public, classes outside the package can reference it directly, which is counter to your intent.

Why isn't `datasource` a `File` instead of a `String`?

Use `try-with-resources` to ensure closeables are handled correctly.

Always catch the most specific exception possible.

It's considered a good practice to hold a reference to a logger as either an instance or static member variable rather than fetching one as needed. It makes the code easier to read. You may also want to do yourself a favor and look into SLF4J/Logback, which are light-years ahead of java.util.logging.

`row` should be a method-level variable, not an instance variable.

`find` should be a `boolean`, not a `Boolean`, and it should be inside the method, not outside it.

I assume that POI needs the file open to access the workbook contents. If not, you should create a method that loads the workbook and then returns it, closing the file immediately rather than holding it through the loop.

The way to attack the repetition problem is to pass in a function that takes a `XSSFRow` and tells you whether or not you have a match. In java 8, you can do this directly. In java 7, you need to define an interface and concrete implementations. This gives you the flexibility to pass in different matchers besides just "column x = y".

If your data size is manageable, you might also consider just loading the whole file into memory in two `Map`s - a `Map<Integer, Person>` and a `Map<String, Person>`. This depends on the actual scope of work you need to do - much more feasible for a toy app or school assignment than a serious production environment with multiple massive files.

I threw together a few quick modifications to ExcelDB which might help kickstart your design:

```
final class ExcelDB implements Repository {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(ExcelDB.class.getName());
    private static final File DATASOURCE = new File("src/doc/Classeur1.xlsx");

    public ExcelDB() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public Person getPersonById(final int id) {
        return this.queryExcel(new IntMatcher(0, id));
    }

    @Override
    public Person getPersonByName(final String name) {
        return this.queryExcel(new StringMatcher(1, name));
    }

    private Person queryExcel(final Matcher matcher) {
        try (final FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(DATASOURCE)) {
            final XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
            final XSSFSheet spreadsheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
            final Iterator<Row> rowIterator = spreadsheet.iterator();

            // Skip header
            rowIterator.next();
            while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
                final XSSFRow row = rowIterator.next();
                if (matcher.matches(row)) {
                    return new Person(
                            row.getCell(0).getNumericCellValue(),
                            row.getCell(1).getStringCellValue());
                }
            }
        } catch (final IOException e) {
            LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
        }
        return null;
    }

    private interface Matcher {
        boolean matches(final XSSFRow row);
    }

    private static final class IntMatcher implements Matcher {

        private final int column;
        private final int value;

        public IntMatcher(final int column, final int value) {
            this.column = column;
            this.value = value;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean matches(final XSSFRow row) {
            return row.getCell(this.column).getNumericCellValue() == this.value;
        }
    }

    private static final class StringMatcher implements Matcher {

        private final int column;
        private final String value;

        public StringMatcher(final int column, final String value) {
            this.column = column;
            this.value = value;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean matches(final XSSFRow row) {
            return row.getCell(this.column).getStringCellValue().equals(this.value);
        }

    }
}
```